# What does the AVL stand for in AVL tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

An AVL tree is the same as a self-balancing binary search tree. What does AVL stand for? Does it have to do with the name of the inventor?

Comment: I downvoted this question because it shows absolutely no initiative on the OP's part to answer his own question. Typing the question into any search engine reveals the answer in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the name of the inventors like you guessed. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree):

> AVL tree is named after its two Soviet inventors, Georgy **A**delson-**V**elsky and Evgenii **L**andis

Their names spell the acronym, **AVL**.

Answer (score 1):

An AVL tree is another balanced binary search tree. Named after their inventors, Adelson-Velskii and Landis, they were the first dynamically balanced trees to be proposed. Like red-black trees, they are not perfectly balanced, but pairs of sub-trees differ in height by at most 1, maintaining an O(logn) search time. Addition and deletion operations also take O(logn) time.

Reference https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/AVL.html